# How to detect and get input fields inside iframe elements from a browser extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, password-manager

I'm trying to create a **chrome browser extension mv3** for a **password manager**, which gets all the inputs from a page, detects their type and the form they are in. According to that information, a dropdown with different content is attached to the page DOM, placed around the input.

I'm having a `let allInputElements = [];` variable inside the content_scripts.js, which I update with the page inputs on every DOM change. And after I have the input elements from the page, I iterate over the array and attach my custom elements to the DOM.

So far, so good ...

This is working fine, except the time when there are inputs inside an iframe element.

To have access to the page iframes, I added the following to the manifest file `"all_frames": true`

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["content_scripts.css"],
      "js": ["content_scripts.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```

This way, the content_scripts.js is called for each frame and each instance of the script has its own array of inputs `allInputElements`. Also each instance is changing the context of the document object.

To get the input elements from the iframe, I tried to communicate with it, sending a `postMessage`. This way I successfully get to the iframe elements, but `allInputElements` has its own instance for each iframe.

I also tried to send the inputs to background.js, and then send them back to the active tab with frameid: 0, but I came to the conclusion that I cannot pass DOM elements through messages.

```
const requestIframeInputs = (iframesArray) => {
  iframesArray.forEach(iframe => {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
      type: 'get_iframe_inputs',
      message: {},
    }, '*');
  });
};

const listenForIframeInputs = (callback) => {
  const eventCallback = (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'get_iframe_inputs') {
      let inputs = event.target.document.querySelectorAll("input, select");
      inputs = filterInputs(inputs);

      if (inputs.length) {
        callback([...inputs]);
      }
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('message', eventCallback, false);
};

const iframeElements = getIframeElements();

if (iframeElements.length) {
  listenForIframeInputs((inputs) => {
    console.log("iframe inputs", inputs);
  });

  requestIframeInputs(iframeElements);
};
```

Is there a way I can have an array of all the inputs from the page, including those from each iframe, and later on dispatch events as "change" or "focus" on them?

And how, after I have all the input elements, I can attach a custom element for each input to the page DOM? Currently I manage to attach them, but inside each iframe instead. This is because the content_scripts.js is called for each one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm sure you can achieve what you're trying to do without having an array of elements from different origins in the same context. For example, the content script attached to the top window will not be able to modify an iframe's DOM if it is not from the same origin.

Comment: DOM elements cannot be sent between cross-origin frames/pages.